# How to remove the text decoration of React Link?

Tags: css, reactjs, hyperlink

I am using React and react-router-doms `Link` component to navigate between pages.

But I am struggling with removing the text-decoration in the component.

React:

`<Link className="nav-link" to="/page">LINK</Link>`

CSS:

```
.nav-link  {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

This CSS does not seem to work, but when I replace the `Link` to a `a` component it works fine.

`<a className="nav-link" href="/page">LINK</a>`

Anyone has an idea how to remove the text-decoration from a Link component?

Comment: You can try to add !important

Comment: Create a selector that has better [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: if u use the style after to="" it will work.

Answer (score 10):

If **react-router** is less than **v4**

Try inline style

```
<Link to="first" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
  Link
</Link>
```

If you want to use styled-components, you could do something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';


const StyledLink = styled(Link)`
    text-decoration: none;

    &:focus, &:hover, &:visited, &:link, &:active {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
`;

export default (props) => <StyledLink {...props} />;
```

**OR**

You can do it with `NavLink` in **react-router v4**

```
 <NavLink
   className="tags"
   activeStyle={{ color: 'red' }}
   to={'/page'}
 >
   LINK
 </NavLink>
```